# Adding API Gateway as Trigger to Lambda Function Using Serverless Script not the UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway, aws-lambda-edge

I want to write a script/code/serverless script that when run adds a trigger to the specified Lambda function.
I can deploy a lambda function using a script, I have added a trigger by going to the aws console and clicking the options from there, Also added a post method to trigger the lambda.
I want to do this using a piece of code/ script that can run on was cli or anywhere.
Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using CLI or scripts you can use AWS CDK to deploy Infrastructure as Code.

For creating and deploying lambda with API Gateway check [this example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/serverless_example.html).

You can get yourself familiar with AWS CDK from [this workshop](https://cdkworkshop.com).
There are many other resources available on internet as well.

Comment: is it possible to do it via a script/code on CLI or terminal?